# Need help with basic function - Python

Tags: python

want to count the number of times a letter appears in a string, having issues here. any help

```
def countLetters(string, character):
    count = 0
    for character in string:
        if character == character:
            count = count + 1
    print count
```

Comment: Yep, `character == character` is going to be very true all the time.

Comment: Avoid using standard library names (`string`) or builtins as variable names.

Comment: Theres a new "Counter" object in python 2.7 collections that contains some useful methods for common count manipulations, like "most_common(n)". http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#counter-objects

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, except for NaN! `float('nan') == float('nan') == False`

Comment: @carl: ...and for objects where you've redefined `__eq__` to do something else. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same variable name for those `character`s (which means they'll always be equal). Try:

```
def countLetters(string, character):
    count = 0
    for char in string:
        if char == character:
            count = count + 1
    print count
```

Of course this is the same as [`str.count()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)

Comment: Thanks, this seems correct but I'm getting this error in IDLE

>>> countLetters(california, a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    countLetters(california, a)
NameError: name 'california' is not defined
>>>

Comment: never mind, stupid comment. I had to add the quote marks.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 10):

The others have covered the errors of your function. Here's an alternative way of doing what you want. Python's built-in string method [count()](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html) returns the number of occurrences of a string.

```
x = "Don't reinvent the wheel."
x.count("e")
```

Gives:

```
5
```

Comment: What about `x = reduce(operator.add, (char == 'e' for char in "Do reinvent the wheel"))`?

Comment: `sum(char == 'e' for char in "Reinvent the wheel another way") == 6`. Much nicer than `reduce` and `operator.add`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if character == character:
```

`character` will always equal `character` because they're the same variable. Just change the names of those variables. Maybe `search_character`?

I also wouldn't use `string` as a variable name since it's the name of a built-in module.